# Return back to first activity from third and skipping the second activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an online ordering system and where user have to make a payment transaction, it takes atleast two steps.  Users selects the item and moved to the new screen which is a new activity, for selection of payment. 
This new activity have different modes of payment, each payment type opens up its own respective active.
Recycler view adapter(items) 
First activity(selection of payment)
second activity(payment processing)
now from the second activity upon successful payment transaction I want to go back to the recycler view adapter which have items.

Please suggest what would be the right approach for achieving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launch the 1st activity from the 3rd with the `CLEAR_TOP` flag.

See [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) for reference.

Edit: this is how you make a Singleton

```
object MySingleton {
    var data: MyDataObject? = null
}
```

in your 3rd activity, you can do

```
MySingleton.data = MyDataObject(/* populate */)
```

then you read it in the 1st

```
MySingleton.data.<property here>
```

Comment: I don't want to start the 1st activity. I want to go back to the adapter with the same item selected which user had clicked.

Comment: That's what this flag does. If the activity is already running (which in this case it is) it just brings it back to the front and removes any activity that was on top of it.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear here. On returning back to the first activity I want to invoke a method. I think it should be achieved through a callback method but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: If you need to pass info back to the activity then you can use `startActivityForResult` or use an object that can be accessed by both activities at the same time. If you were to use Fragments I would suggest a shared viewmodel scoped to the Activity. If you are using activities, you could have a Singleton object used to hold the data.
You can also a pass it in the start intent as a payload and parse it on the 1st activity.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. could you show me how to make singleton object through code. It would be really nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can start intent with flag

```
 val intent = Intent(this, Activity1::class.java)
 intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
 startActivity(intent)
```

Or you can call `finishAffinity()` after start a new activity

```
 val intent = Intent(this, Activity1::class.java)
 startActivity(intent)
 finishAffinity()
```